# New Page with controller in prestashop redirects to home page

Tags: redirect, url-rewriting, controller, prestashop

I added a new page with a controller in prestashop, and when try to go to the page, it redirects to home-page.

Url rewrite is enabled and even when the link for the page is taken via

```
{$link->getPageLink('pagename.php')}
```

and it gives a modified link, still that link is also redirects to home-page.

I tried to regenerate htaccess but still no luck.

Comment: I resolved the issue later by removing the php extension from the pagename. Now it looks like this: 
{$link->getPageLink('pagename')}

Answer (score 1):

You have to add the page under "Preferences > SEO & URLs".